# API integration between two companies Tibco

Tags: integration, tibco

This is a new subject for me so apologies for potentially a stupid question.

An API needs to be designed to query and get some data between two companies. Company-1 uses Tibco for integration and interconnecting its systems/applications so the benefit is clear there.
Company-2 does not have Tibco (and does not intend to implement it).

Is there any Tibco integration needed or beneficial for Company-1 ?
Would be the best approach just create secure connectivity between the two companies and use API without any Tibco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking of REST / JSON APIs and you are wondering if Company-2 would get some benefits using TIBCO to call APIs exposed by Company-1 using TIBCO.

While the use of REST / JSON APIs is generally based on a standard format defined by a Swagger or Open API specification file, Company-2 can use the technology of its choice to call the APIs exposed by Company-1. This can be a Java toolkit like Spring, an Integration solution similar to TIBCO or any other solution that would fit Company-2 requirements (Python scripts, a low code development tool, etc).